# count(a.selected_he = "yes") is OK?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I ask like that:

```
having count(a.selected_he = "yes") > 2
```

I want to ask if the count of the results records that `selected_he = yes` are more than `2`.
But I'm not sure I can write `a.selected_he = "yes"` in count function.

Am I right?

Comment: Why don't you try for yourself? Questions like "Can I do this or that?" can usually  be answered faster if you actually try it yourself.

Comment: Try sum() instead. The boolean result of the comparison will get cast to an int (0 or 1) and both will be "counted". But if you sum(), then you'll add up only the `true` values.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN a.selected_he='yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>2 FROM ...
```

`count` counts non-`null`s, not `true`s.

Comment: Yes, it would. of course you can `count(case when a.select_he='yes' then 1 else null end)`, but why would you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,count(*) as counts
from table
where selected_he = 'yes'
group by id
having counts > 2
```

if column in where clause does not contain nulls.

Comment: Assuming the OP wants to filter out the rest, having sounds like a good choice. But context is not well defined here.